# PHP Laravel schedule command to run once across all servers

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I'm trying to figure out if I can run schedule a command to run across all servers.

Currently I have a command `clean:directories` and I run it like this:

```
$schedule->command('clean:directories')->daily();
```

It scans the filesystem and removes files older than a set date. I need it to run on a queue server rather than just on the main.

Update: for now I've added an entry to crontab on the specific server I would like this ran on

Comment: Why not put the command just in your queue server then, so it'd only run on queue server.

Comment: This depends on your setup. In our setup the scheduler runs every minute on all servers because it's in the crontab of the server image so the command will run on all servers. How is your setup?

Answer (score 0):

If your Laravel application is deployed to multiple servers, you should think about adding the `schedule:run` command on each of them as a linux cronjob.

Laravel Docs:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

[Running the Scheduler (Laravel Docs)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)

Before you add the schedule:run command on your other servers you should be in mind, that **all** of your kernel defined jobs will be executed on **all** servers. If you have commands, which require only an execution once, you should improve your commands with the `onOneServer()` method. * *(See requirements below)*

Official Laravel Docs:

> If your application's scheduler is running on multiple servers, you may limit a scheduled job to only execute on a single server. For instance, assume you have a scheduled task that generates a new report every Friday night. If the task scheduler is running on three worker servers, the scheduled task will run on all three servers and generate the report three times. Not good!

[Running Tasks on One Server (Laravel Docs)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-tasks-on-one-server)

---

`onOneServer` Requirements:

> To utilize this feature, your application must be using the **database**, **memcached**, **dynamodb**, or **redis** cache driver as your application's default cache driver. In addition, all servers must be communicating with the same central cache server.